# I cannot read child elements in an xdocument

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

This is my XML:

```
<HelpDesk xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/blahblahblah" 
          xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Email>helpdesk@company.com</Email>
    <Phone>1-800-867-5309</Phone>
    <URL>https://www.company.com/</URL>
</HelpDesk>
```

I receive the string of text ( shown above ) from a web service. I then use the following to create an XDocument object:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(responseString)
```

I'm trying to grab the Email, Phone, and URL information. I've tried a lot of things but I simply cannot get hold of the child nodes.

The last things I have tried are following but still, nothing:

```
Dim email As String = doc.Root.Element("Email").Value
Dim email As String = doc.Element("Email").Value
```

What is it I'm doing wrong? This surely can't be that complicated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I get the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object for the two attempts.

And, I get the same exception when I try Andrew's suggestion

```
Dim email As String = doc.Element("HelpDesk").Element("Email").Value
```

Comment: Did you try `Dim email As String = doc.Element("HelpDesk").Element("Email").Value`?

Comment: @Andrew: yep. I get the following Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not respecting the **XML namespace** in the document!

```
<HelpDesk xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/blahblahblah" 
          ************************************************************
```

This is a XML namespace - and you need to pay attention to it, respect it, include it on your queries.

Use this code - and pay attention to the XML namespace - and then you should be fine:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(responseString)

' define the XNamespace that you need!    
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/blahblahblah"

' include the XNamespace in your XPath query    
Dim emailNode = doc.Root.Descendants(ns & "Email").FirstOrDefault()

If emailNode IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim email As String = emailNode.Value
End If
```

You should **also** always be defensive about your programming - don't just blindly assume that a call works - **check for it!**. Therefore - don't just blindly assume that `emailNode` is valid - it *could* be null! Check for that - only access it's `.Value` property if it's `!= null` ....

Comment: This worked :) Could you explain why the namespace is necessary and why you used .Descendants?

Comment: "You should also always be defensive about your programming - don't just blindly assume that a call works - check for it!. Therefore - don't just blindly assume that emailNode is valid - it could be null! Check for that - only access it's .Value property if it's != null ...."
I totally agree with this statement

Comment: @curioususer: namespaces in XML are just like namespaces in VB.NET - a means to organize things into logical buckets. I use `.Descendants` out of habit, probably :-) You could also use `.Element()` or `.Elements()`

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. I don't have a ton of experience with XML so this really has helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Select the proper node using LINQ

```vb
Dim contact As XElement =
    <HelpDesk xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/blahblahblah" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Email>helpdesk@company.com</Email>
        <Phone>1-800-867-5309</Phone>
        <URL>https://www.company.com/</URL>
    </HelpDesk>
Dim responseString = contact.ToString()
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(responseString)

Dim email = doc.Root.Elements.Where(Function(xe) xe.Name.LocalName = "Email").FirstOrDefault().Value
Dim phone = doc.Root.Elements.Where(Function(xe) xe.Name.LocalName = "Phone").FirstOrDefault().Value
Dim url = doc.Root.Elements.Where(Function(xe) xe.Name.LocalName = "URL").FirstOrDefault().Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not return results because you ignore the namespace to which your nodes belong, requesting the empty namespace instead.

You get the "Object reference not set to" on that instead of an empty string because you are using the C# way of accessing XML.

To fix both problems, add the XML namespace declaration to the beginning of your code module:

```vb
Imports <xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/blahblahblah">
Imports <xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

And query the XML as you would in VB:

```vb
Dim email As String = doc.<HelpDesk>.<Email>.Value
```

The namespace `Import`ed as the default `xmlns` namespace will automatically apply to all unqualified queries in this module. If you find this confusing, you can instead declare that namespace with some other prefix, e.g.

```vb
Imports <xmlns:x="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/blahblahblah">
```

and then it would be

```vb
Dim email As String = doc.<x:HelpDesk>.<x:Email>.Value
```

When querying XML this way, you don't have to worry about some nodes down the query path being `null` or absent. If they are, the whole query will return an empty string without raising an exception.

Comment: I gave this a quick shot but it did not work for me, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep playing around with this to see if I can get it to work for me.